# Reading an Excel file in python using pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to read an excel file this way :

```
newFile = pd.ExcelFile(PATH\FileName.xlsx)
ParsedData = pd.io.parsers.ExcelFile.parse(newFile)
```

which throws an error that says two arguments expected, I don't know what the second argument is and also what I am trying to achieve here is to convert an Excel file to a DataFrame, Am I doing it the right way? or is there any other way to do this using pandas?

Answer (score 258, accepted):

Close: first you call `ExcelFile`, but then you call the `.parse` method and pass it the sheet name.

```
>>> xl = pd.ExcelFile("dummydata.xlsx")
>>> xl.sheet_names
[u'Sheet1', u'Sheet2', u'Sheet3']
>>> df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
>>> df.head()
                  Tid  dummy1    dummy2    dummy3    dummy4    dummy5  \
0 2006-09-01 00:00:00       0  5.894611  0.605211  3.842871  8.265307   
1 2006-09-01 01:00:00       0  5.712107  0.605211  3.416617  8.301360   
2 2006-09-01 02:00:00       0  5.105300  0.605211  3.090865  8.335395   
3 2006-09-01 03:00:00       0  4.098209  0.605211  3.198452  8.170187   
4 2006-09-01 04:00:00       0  3.338196  0.605211  2.970015  7.765058   

     dummy6  dummy7    dummy8    dummy9  
0  0.623354       0  2.579108  2.681728  
1  0.554211       0  7.210000  3.028614  
2  0.567841       0  6.940000  3.644147  
3  0.581470       0  6.630000  4.016155  
4  0.595100       0  6.350000  3.974442
```

What you're doing is calling the method which lives on the class itself, rather than the instance, which is okay (although not very idiomatic), but if you're doing that you would also need to pass the sheet name:

```
>>> parsed = pd.io.parsers.ExcelFile.parse(xl, "Sheet1")
>>> parsed.columns
Index([u'Tid', u'dummy1', u'dummy2', u'dummy3', u'dummy4', u'dummy5', u'dummy6', u'dummy7', u'dummy8', u'dummy9'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: when I use "df = xl.parse("Sheet1")" it automatically takes the first cell's value of each column as the dataframe's column names , how do I specify my own column names?

Comment: In pandas 15.0.2,  `parsed = pd.io.parsers.ExcelFile.parse(xl, "Sheet1")` does not work and throws error `module object has no attribute ExcelFile` . 
`parsed = pd.io.excel.ExcelFile.parse(xl, "Sheet1")` works for me

Comment: Nice. This is almost as neat as how the same accessing of a tab is achieved using `openpyxl`. Is pandas calling openpyxl under the hood?

Comment: How do you prevent it from turning the first row into headers? I've tried using the parameter `headers=None`but while it didn't break the code, it didn't work either.

Comment: I discovered that **pip install xlrd** is needed for this to work.  The xlrd package  doesn't come with pandas, so if you didn't install it for some other purpose, you'll get a "ImportError: No module named xlrd" exception.  True as of pandas 0.19.0 on Mac, at any rate.

Comment: @user5920660 True as of Ubuntu too, and it must be `xlrd >= 0.9.0`!

Answer (score 110):

This is much simple and easy way.

```py
import pandas
df = pandas.read_excel(open('your_xls_xlsx_filename','rb'), sheetname='Sheet 1')
# or using sheet index starting 0
df = pandas.read_excel(open('your_xls_xlsx_filename','rb'), sheetname=2)
```

Check out [documentation full details](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.read_excel.html).

FutureWarning: The `sheetname` keyword is deprecated for newer Pandas versions, use `sheet_name` instead.

Answer (score 22):

Thought i should add here, that if you want to access rows or columns to loop through them, you do this:

```
import pandas as pd

# open the file
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile("PATH\FileName.xlsx")

# get the first sheet as an object
sheet1 = xlsx.parse(0)
    
# get the first column as a list you can loop through
# where the is 0 in the code below change to the row or column number you want    
column = sheet1.icol(0).real

# get the first row as a list you can loop through
row = sheet1.irow(0).real
```

---

**Edit:**

The methods `icol(i)` and `irow(i)` are deprecated now. You can use `sheet1.iloc[:,i]` to get the i-th col and `sheet1.iloc[i,:]` to get the i-th row.

Answer (score 18):

I think this should satisfy your need:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the excel sheet to pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_excel("PATH\FileName.xlsx", sheet_name=0) #corrected argument name
```

Comment: FYI the correct argument name is `sheet_name` not `sheetname`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an updated method with syntax that is more common in python code. It also prevents you from opening the same file multiple times.

```
import pandas as pd

sheet1, sheet2 = None, None
with pd.ExcelFile("PATH\FileName.xlsx") as reader:
    sheet1 = pd.read_excel(reader, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    sheet2 = pd.read_excel(reader, sheet_name='Sheet2')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 1):

You just need to feed the path to your file to `pd.read_excel`

```py
import pandas as pd

file_path = "./my_excel.xlsx"
data_frame = pd.read_excel(file_path)
```

Checkout [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to explore parameters like `skiprows` to ignore rows when loading the excel

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel (r'**YourPath**.xlsx')

print (data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading an excel file without explicitly naming a sheet but instead giving the number of the sheet order (often one will simply load the first sheet) goes like:

```
import pandas as pd
myexcel = pd.ExcelFile("C:/filename.xlsx")
myexcel = myexcel.parse(myexcel.sheet_names[0])
```

Since `.sheet_names` returns a list of sheet names, it is easy to load one or more sheets by simply calling the list element(s).

Answer (score 0):

All of these works for me

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.read_excel('FileName.xlsx') # If there is only one sheet in the excel file

In [3]: df = pd.read_excel('FileName.xlsx', sheet_name=0)

In [4]: In [20]: df = pd.read_excel('FileName.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet 1')
```

Answer (score 0):

#load pandas library

import pandas as pd

#set path where the file is

path = "./myfile.xlsx"

#load the file into dataframe df

df = pd.read_excel(path)

#check the first 5 rows

df.head(5)

Comment: Thanks for adding this, but this just duplicates a subset of existing answers.  Also,  next time please format code by enclosing it in triple backticks.