# Reading an excel data set saved as CSV file in pandas

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

There is a very similar question to the one I am about to ask posted here:

[Reading an Excel file in python using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063458/reading-an-excel-file-in-python-using-pandas)

Except when I attempt to use the solutions posted here I am countered with

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'read'

All I want to do is convert this excel sheet into the pandas format so that I can preform data analysis on some of the subjects of my table. I am super new to this so any information, advice, feedback or whatever that anybody could toss my way would be greatly appreciated.

Heres my code:

```
import pandas
file = pandas.read_csv('FILENAME.csv', 'rb')
# reads specified file name from my computer in Pandas format
print file.read()
```

By the way, I also tried running the same query with 
    file = pandas.read_excel('FILENAME.csv', 'rb')  returning the same error.

Finally, when I try to resave the file as a .xlsx I am unable to open the document.

Cheers!

Comment: `file` is already a `DataFrame` pandas object.

Comment: OK thanks, does that mean I should just drop the whole 'file =' ?

Comment: Well, `file` isn't a good name for the variable, but that doesn't really matter. Regardless, you need to have a variable or else you won't be able to access the data.

Comment: Just change `file =` to `df =` (a common but not necessary naming convention) and try, for example, `df[:5]`

Comment: Thanks Jeff I just tried that edit and its still returning the same error:

TypeError: descriptor 'read' of 'file' object needs an argument

Comment: Also, if you are working with csv's you probably won't need anything other than the `pandas.read_csv` function to read your data into a `DataFrame`.  The reason you should avoid `file` as a name for one of your variables is that the `file` identifier is already used in python 2 (although not in 3) for the built-in `file` function, and you shouldn't overwrite names of built-ins.

Comment: **Don't** use file.read(). There is no need for it.

Comment: OK great, I got rid of the file.read() and it came back with no errors but now its not showing the resulting table. Any advice on showing the table?

Comment: Never mind I figured that one out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message means exactly what it says: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'read'`

When you use  [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) you're actually reading the `csv` file into a dataframe. BTW, you don't need the `'rb'`

```
df = pandas.read_csv('FILENAME.csv')
```

You can `print (df)` but you can not do `print(df.read())` because the dataframe object doesn't have a `.read()` attribute. This is what's causing your error.

Comment: Amazing, thanks a bunch Joe, that did the trick, and I am back on track with my project thanks to you!

Comment: @JustinT I am glad to hear that! So, you can click the answer as the right answer. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

read_csv() return a dataframe by itself so there is no need to convert it, just save it into dataframe.

I think this should work

```
import pandas as pd #It is best practice to import package with as a short name. Makes it easier to reference later. 
file = pd.read_csv('FILENAME.csv')
print (file)
```