# SQL Server to Excel to Python - pd.read_excel()

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

Is there a way to read an excel table in python - when the table you're reading is actually an excel table connected to SQL Server?

In theory - i'm asking if you can go from a data linked excel file to a python pandas dataframe, pd.read_excel() doesn't seem to work for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading an Excel file in python using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063458/reading-an-excel-file-in-python-using-pandas)

Comment: did you mean `pd.read_excel()` instead of `pd.read_csv()`?

Comment: yes - read_excel

Comment: can you read the table instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: [Reading an Excel file in python using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063458/reading-an-excel-file-in-python-using-pandas)

```
>>> xl = pd.ExcelFile("dummydata.xlsx")
>>> xl.sheet_names
[u'Sheet1', u'Sheet2', u'Sheet3']
>>> df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just import your data from SQL Server?  What does Excel even have to do with this???

```
import pypyodbc 
cnxn = pypyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                        "Server=Your_Server_Name;"
                        "Database=Your_DB_Name;"
                        "Trusted_Connection=yes;")


cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Customers')

for row in cursor:
    print('row = %r' % (row,))
```

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more. The hiccup is that I'm working with legacy workbooks that are actually linked to SQL server data without the SQL server credentials. So as I read the excel tables (that were linked to SSMS), pandas weren't reading the tables appropriately.