# How to read a .xlsx with pd.read

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a xlsx file but when i run the code I have the next issue. Can someone suggest me how to fix it!

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [18.0, 8.0]
import re
import string


leyes = pd.read_pickle('C:\\Users\\diese\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\GitHub\\MCPP_diego_ramirez\\Proyectof\\leyes.xlsx')



 A load persistent id instruction was encountered,but no persistent_load function was specified.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading an Excel file in python using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063458/reading-an-excel-file-in-python-using-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)?

```
frame = pd.read_excel('filen.xlsx', engine='xlrd')
```

Comment: Oh, that was easy. Thanks a lot