# Read in an Excel Form to Pandas - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel sheet that has an excel form like this,

[image]

I want to read this into Pandas, and have my Data Frame. I tried to read using a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063458/reading-an-excel-file-in-python-using-pandas), but I am not getting what I want because of my file. In the picture you see can see `Scope Changes` and `amt`. I don't need those info. I only need the `info` and other details such as `Name` until `zipcode`.

Eventually, I need a data frame similar to this,

```
          Info
Name      Integral
Type      Sport&Entertainment
Type 1    Racetrack
...
```

How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: You can slice the specific rows once you read in the file. If the data you need were in columns instead of rows, you could also use the "use_cols()" method. But In this particular case, I think that you will need to create another object that is a slice of the DataFrame. Once you read the DataFrame, i'd slice it and store that value in a variable. The slice can simply include the rows of data (such as name) that you want to actually work with.

Comment: Is `Scope Changes` the first row?  Please show more of your data.

Comment: @James No, it is not the first row. Also, I have 23 different files like this that I want get data from. All of them have same form, but in different row numbers.

Comment: @Simeon Ikudabo yes, that is a good suggestion. For one file it might be good try that I will try. Any suggestions if I have many files with different row numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at another method of getting this information. Instead of an excel spreadsheet could they enter the information into a google form that is attached to a google sheet? You’re trying to use a form that’s optimized for end users to do data analysis.