# How to replace a particular Column of a dataFrame with another DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

While i was playing with a Excel dataset where i gave two  DataFrames `data_xls` and `seggCol`.  Where `data_xls`  having the column `'Internal Link Tracking (non-promotions) - ENT (c20)'` which i want to be replaced with all of the columns from `seggCol` dataFrame.

However while looking something `df.join` or `df.concat` i'm not really getting the way to do it.

Saying that DataFrame `data_xls`'s   column  `[Internal Link Tracking (non-promotions) - ENT (c20)]`   will be replaced by another DataFrame `seggCol`s  columns `['Internal Link Tracking', 'Campaign Name', 'Creative', 'Action', 'Action 2']`

**FIrst DataFrame:**

DataFrame columns...

```
   >>> data_xls.columns
    Index(['Date', 'Internal Link Tracking (non-promotions) - ENT (c20)', 'BFY_LinkedIn_SponsoredContent_Visits', 'BFY_LinkedIn_inMail_Visits', 'BFY_DBM_Native_Visits',
           'BFY_SGCPB_Native_Visits', 'BFY_SGCBDC_Email_Visits', 'BFY_SGCPB_Email_Visit', 'BFY_SGCBDC_Native_Visits', 'BFY_ConstructionDive_Email_Visit',
           'BFY_ConstructionDive_PromotedStory_Visit', 'BFY_SGCPB_PromotedStory_Visit', 'BFY_SGCBDC_PromotedStory_Visit', 'BFY_ConstructionDive_Native_Visits'],
          dtype='object')
```

DataFrame Structure..

```
>>> data_xls.head()
        Date Internal Link Tracking (non-promotions) - ENT (c20)  BFY_LinkedIn_SponsoredContent_Visits  BFY_LinkedIn_inMail_Visits  BFY_DBM_Native_Visits  \
0 2018-08-20         us-campaign-article1-scrolldown-findoutnow                                      0                           0                      0
1 2018-08-20                   us-campaign-article1-scrollright                                      0                           0                      0
2 2018-08-20                    us-campaign-article1-findoutnow                                      1                           0                      1
3 2018-08-20          us-campaign-payablesmanagement-findoutnow                                      0                           0                      0
4 2018-08-20        us-campaign-strategicpurchasing-scrollright                                      0                           0                      0

   BFY_SGCPB_Native_Visits  BFY_SGCBDC_Email_Visits  BFY_SGCPB_Email_Visit  BFY_SGCBDC_Native_Visits  BFY_ConstructionDive_Email_Visit  \
0                        0                        0                      0                         0                                 0
1                        0                        0                      0                         0                                 0
2                        0                        0                      0                         0                                 0
3                        0                        0                      0                         0                                 0
4                        0                        0                      0                         0                                 0

   BFY_ConstructionDive_PromotedStory_Visit  BFY_SGCPB_PromotedStory_Visit  BFY_SGCBDC_PromotedStory_Visit  BFY_ConstructionDive_Native_Visits
0                                         0                              0                               0                                   0
1                                         0                              0                               0                                   0
2                                         0                              0                               0                                   0
3                                         0                              0                               0                                   0
4                                         0                              0                               0                                   0
```

**Second DataFrame:**

DataFrame Columns ...

```
   >>> seggCol.columns
        Index(['Internal Link Tracking', 'Campaign Name', 'Creative', 'Action', 'Action 2'], dtype='object')
```

DataFrame Structure..

```
>>> seggCol.head()
  Internal Link Tracking Campaign Name             Creative       Action    Action 2
0                     us      campaign             article1   scrolldown  findoutnow
1                     us      campaign             article1  scrollright        None
2                     us      campaign             article1   findoutnow        None
3                     us      campaign   payablesmanagement   findoutnow        None
4                     us      campaign  strategicpurchasing  scrollright        None
```

**Desired New DataFrame:**

```
           Date Internal Link Tracking     Campaign Name             Creative       Action              Action 2  BFY_LinkedIn_SponsoredContent_Visits  BFY_LinkedIn_inMail_Visits  BFY_DBM_Native_Visits  \
0    2018-08-20                          us      campaign             article1   scrolldown            findoutnow                                     0                           0                      0
23   2018-08-20                          us      campaign             article1    learnmore   strategicpurchasing                                     0                           0                      0
24   2018-08-20                          us      campaign             article1    learnmore  controlandvisibility                                     0                           0                      0
25   2018-08-21                          us      campaign             article1   scrolldown            findoutnow                                     0                           0                      0
26   2018-08-21                          us      campaign             article1  scrollright                  None                                     0                           0                      0
27   2018-08-21                          us      campaign             article1   findoutnow                  None                                     1                           1                      0
28   2018-08-21                          us      campaign   payablesmanagement   findoutnow                  None                                     2                           1                      0
29   2018-08-21                          us      campaign  strategicpurchasing  scrollright                  None                                     3                           2                      1
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/53067066/8320861.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa, NO i saw that , i'm Just thinking another way around replacing one particular column of DataFrame while using another Dataframes all columns.. This is just a another sort of Question on the same data

Comment: Not sure whether there is a direct approach to this type of problem. But, eager to know if exists.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa, that's what i'm looking Forward.. if we can do that way it will easy, hoping some expert solution from pandas experts

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Replace column names with those of yours:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 5, 6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col3': [1, 2, 3], 'col4': [4, 5, 6]})
final_df = pd.concat([df1['col1'], df2, df1['col2']], axis=1)
final_df
```

[image]

**Edit**: Alternatively, you could slice the columns and get the desired output. Replace my variable names with those of yours:

```
final_df = pd.concat([df1.iloc[:,0:1], df2, df1.iloc[:,1:]], axis=1)
```

Comment: @pygo, you need to insert `df2` after the first two columns of `df1`?

Comment: Try `pd.concat([df1.iloc[:,0:1], df2, df1.iloc[:,1:]], axis=1)`, replace variable names with those of yours.

Comment: In `pd.concat([df1.iloc[:,0:1], df2, df1.iloc[:,1:]], axis=1)`, replace variable names with those of yours. You may need to adjust your indexing.

Comment: This either does not work using the iloc option.. it gives weird column alignment

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
concatenation = [data_xls, seggCol]
 result = pd.concat(concatenation)
```

if you want to replace values data_xls['Internal Link Tracking (non-promotions) - ENT (c20)'] with seggCol['Internal Link Tracking']

There is no need to join or concat.

Comment: Oh Sorry I have added two column please try this
data_xls['Internal Link Tracking (non-promotions) - ENT (c20)'] = seggCol['Internal Link Tracking'']

Comment: I think you want to make new data frame which includes values of data_xls and seggCol

Comment: Your solution will not work at all.. there is no logic i see!

Comment: you can add columns from data frame like
 concatenation = [data_xls[['A'],['B']], seggCol[['C'],['D']]]