# How to read csv file and excel file python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the syntax of reading file ,writing file in python.and How to read csv file and excel file in DataFrames(pandas).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading an Excel file in python using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063458/reading-an-excel-file-in-python-using-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')
```

this will result into Dataframe.If you want to read a specific column and want output as series.

```
df=pd.read_csv('file_name.csv',usecols=['col_name'],squeeze=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
   df = pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

To read:

```
df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

To write:

```
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
df.to_excel('filename.xlsx')
```

*if you just googled "pandas read excel"..*

Answer (score 1):

See [pandas.read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) for Excel and [pandas.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for CSV files.