# Importing from Excel in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to import data from an excel file. I would like to import from a specific sheet and in that specific sheet only import certain columns.
The code I am using is as follows:

```
%matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style="darkgrid")

# Input Portfolio data

xl_file=pd.ExcelFile('C:/Users/e877780/Desktop/DEV/S2_SK_S_06_02_input.xlsx')
s2_0602=xl_file.parse("S.06.02")[('C0080','C0090')]
```

My idea is to only import columns C0080 and C0090. I I just use one, it works but also does not keep the column name.
Can someone help
Thks

Comment: Use [pandas read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). You can specify the sheetname and columns to use.

Comment: Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36590692/3250829) from the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
xl_file=pd.ExcelFile('C:/Users/e877780/Desktop/DEV/S2_SK_S_06_02_input.xlsx')
sheet1=xl_file.parse("S.06.02")
s2_0602 = sheet1[['C0080','C0090']]
```

Hope it help

Comment: Thank you. It works fine