# How to find and rename content of excel file with out opening the file?

Tags: python, excel, linux, bash, replace

I have a excelsheet in which row 3 and column E3 has information as below:

```
row1     row2           row3
"H3"    "System Name" linuxtestserver
```

how can I edit that excel sheet with script and replace linuxtestserver with other server name with out opening it?

I have tried sed command it dosent seems to work on excel file

```
sed 's/linuxtestserver/susetestserver/g' test.xls
```

Comment: Try saving the file as .csv instead of .xls

Comment: My Current situation.. i have 100 files which are saved as excel1_linuxtest.xls, excel2_susetest.xls ....excel100_debiantest.xls... i have to open each file and manually edit row 3 and coulmn E3 with linuxtest,susetest,debiantest by replacing exisit content.  the exisiting content will be same.. ex: susetest

Comment: You might want to look into the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) Python package. Some possible starting points for your reading: [Reading an Excel file in python using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063458/reading-an-excel-file-in-python-using-pandas), [pandas.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), [pandas.DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).

Comment: Thank you i wil lcheck.