# Importing excel files into Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, import

I am a super new user of Python and have been having trouble loading an Excel file to play around with in Python.

I am using Python 3.7 on Windows 10 and have tried things like using the import statement or using pip and pip3 and then install statements.  I am so confused on how to do this and no links I've read online are helping.

```
pip install pandas
pip3 install pandas
import pandas
```

I just want to upload an Excel file into Python.  I'm embarrassed that it's causing me this much stress.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading an Excel file in python using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063458/reading-an-excel-file-in-python-using-pandas)

Comment: Did the `pip` commands complete successfully?

Comment: when I type in pip import pandas, I get the following message: SyntaxError: invalid syntax pointing toward the t in import

Comment: Is your import working or are you unaware on how to proceed with ur code?

Comment: @user2813606 - I was referring to `pip install pandas`. `pip import` will definitely not work.

Comment: That doesn't work either

Comment: @user2813606 pip install pandas is a command to be entered on the command line (cmd.exe from windows search) import pandas is a command in a python program or script

Comment: @user2813606 1.) Open cmd.exe 2.)type python and hit enter 3.)type import pandas and hit enter.. let us know the result

Comment: @user2813606 "That doesn't work either" - how does it not work? what's the error message?

Comment: Progress!  Thank you for working with me on this!  I know I'm an idiot.  Next error after trying to run line pd.ExcelFile(path to my file): PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you have to import pandas (assuming that is installed, in anaconda usually is already installed as far as i know)

```
import pandas as pd
```

to read more sheets in different dataframes (tables)

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile(path of your file)
df_schema = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=xls.sheet_names)
```

df_schema is a dictionary of df in which the key is the name of the sheet and the value is the dataframe.

to read a single sheet the following should work:

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile(path of your file)
df = pd.read_excel(xls)
```

Comment: When I type in import pandas as pd, I get the following message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'