# Import all excel sheets from a excel file into pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Hi I have a folder with several excel files, on top every file has severel sheets (for several days). How can I important all of the with pandas? All of the sheets in all the file have the same structure that should not be a problem, but how can I have a big dataframe afterwards? Right now I only now:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob("TransactionData\Promorelevant*.csv")
dfs = [pd.read_excel(f) for f in files]

df = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
```

But how can i load all sheets in all files?

So one excel, lets call it: ExcelA.xlsx, has the Sheets: 01.01, 02.01, 03.01 on it

In this similiar question: [Reading an Excel file in python using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063458/reading-an-excel-file-in-python-using-pandas) it is mentioned how to open 1 sheet, but I getting stucked how to open all sheets together for all files.

Comment: thats not correct with the duplicate....its only mentioned how to read one sheet name, but not all sheet names. I don't get it

Comment: if anyone wants to have the solutions: its here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61745348/error-while-loading-multiple-excel-sheets-into-pandas