# Error while loading multiple excel sheets into pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I try to load multiple excel files with multiple excel sheets into a pandas dataframe, right now I am running:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

files = glob.glob(r'C:\...\Data\*.xlsx')
dfs = pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name=None) for f in files]
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

The none parameter makes sure that I load all sheets in every excel, but i get the error:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type ', only Series and Dataframe objs are valid.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is necessary join `DataFrame`s in first list comprehension, because if pass `sheet_name=None` get Orderdict of DataFrames:

```
dfs = [pd.concat(pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name=None)) for f in files]
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```