# Create a Dataframe from an excel file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want create a Dataframe from excel file. I am using pandas read_excel function. My requirement is to create a Dataframe for all elements if the column matches some value.

For eg:- Below is my excel file and I want to create the Dataframe with all elements that has Module equal to 'DC-Prod'

[Exccel File Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6az9t.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading an Excel file in python using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063458/reading-an-excel-file-in-python-using-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome, Saagar Sheth!

to make a Dataframe, just import "pandas" it like so...

```
import pandas as pd
```

then create a variable for the file to access, like this;

```
file_var_pandas = 'customer_data.xlsx'
```

and then, create its dataframe using the `read_excel`;

```
customers = pd.read_excel(file_var_pandas,
sheetname=0,
header=0,
index_col=False,
keep_default_na=True
)
```

finally, use the `head()` command like so;

```
customers.head()
```

if you want to know more just go to this website!

[Packet Pandas Dataframe](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781785287466/3/ch03lvl1sec45/creating-a-pandas-dataframe-from-an-excel-file)

and have fun!

Comment: Hi Ron, Thanks for the reply. However if you could please refer the snippet of excel file as my requirement is not just creating a dataframe but reading all the row which will have the value in Module column as 'DC-Prod'

Comment: maybe this would help; https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Thanks but i have already checked the pandas documentation. Not much help