# pandas read path without file folder

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\name\Documents\Data\/' + file+ '.xlsx')
```

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\name\Documents\/file.xlsx'

I try this is Documents path and it work, but when I adding one more file folder(Data) to it, python show me that he didn't go in to the Data file folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading an Excel file in python using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063458/reading-an-excel-file-in-python-using-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code would help you

```
file = 'sample'
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\Data\\' + file+ '.xlsx')
```

or

`\` backslash sometimes behave as escape sequences.
To avoid that situation

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/name/Documents/Data/' + file+ '.xlsx')
```

Comment: I try this 2 code already, but the error is still the same

Comment: updated the code with sample file name. also give the correct path.. in your example there is no folder name data.

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\/sample.xlsx'  the path still not go inside the Data folder which the sample file is located

Comment: there no / in my code before the file name sample. kindly copy the code and work or use the second option in my code

Comment: thanks for your helping, I edit the wrong file in the document folder, they got the same name...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that last / before file