# Reading Excel sheet that is constantly updated using python

Tags: python, excel, algorithmic-trading

So i have an excel sheet that dumps the LTP of a stock (right now it is manual) also the stoploss is updated constantly in the excel sheet.
Now the problem is how will i use this excel sheet(that is constantly updated) and place order in my broker terminal.
I know you can routinely open the excel sheet after a fixed time. How do i solve this problem?

Secondly i use Ms Office to open the excel sheet and keep it open for updating the data. In my python program it says that the excel is opened in another program. How to get around this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063458/reading-an-excel-file-in-python-using-pandas?r=SearchResults&s=4|50.7201 could help

Comment: Would you explain which problem you are identifying as the *problem*?  That the excel sheet is constantly updated, or how to place an order in the broker terminal?  Or python complaining about sharing a data file?

Comment: also making a copy of the file and using that, would avoid "excel is opened in another program"

Comment: @wallyk yes. The excel sheet is constantly updated that is my problem.