# Reading and Writing Excel (XLSX) Files in Python with the Pandas Library

Tags: python

You are required to read data from excel, perform simple processing/calculation, and write back some data to the file using Pandas library. You can also use other library to perform related task
Deliverables:

1. Print screen of source code and its output
2. Source code
3. Data source

Comment: Who is _required to read data from excel, …_?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading an Excel file in python using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063458/reading-an-excel-file-in-python-using-pandas)