# Panda datafram from excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Hi I'm working on a script, and I can't figure out how to accomplish
-I have an excel file with student INFO
-I wanna add that data to a PANDAS data frame
-but I can't(or IDK how, yet) since I gotta make a code dynamic so it does it by itself regardless of how many student I have at that moment
IDK if I explained myself correctly...
here is the code, I'll appreciate any help

```
path = "database.xlsx" #location
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This is to read excell and take SIDG variable which is (Students ID Given) so the script knows 
# how many lines he's dealing with, and their position...
#
#
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path) #----To open the workbook, workbook object is created 
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active #----------------Get workbook active sheet object, from the active attribute 
obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = 1, column = 1)#-Assign obj variable a cell in the excel 
yet_to_convert_SIDG = obj.value #----------assign cell value to SIDG variable
SIDG = int(yet_to_convert_SIDG)#-----------assign to SIDG the integer converted value of yet_to_convert
to_load = SIDG + 2 #-----------------------it just tell the code the line where the Student info 
#                                          start, which is the second row of the excel
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

data = [] # variable for data set# variable where the LIST from the excel will be stored
x = 0 #variable to append data list to dataframe PANDA
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    while to_load > 2: # to process database
        #assign a variable to certain cell
        loading_id = sheet_obj.cell(row = to_load, column = 1)
        loading_dl = sheet_obj.cell(row = to_load, column = 2)
        loading_fn = sheet_obj.cell(row = to_load, column = 3)
        loading_ln = sheet_obj.cell(row = to_load, column = 4)
        loading_dob = sheet_obj.cell(row = to_load, column = 5)
        loading_ssn = sheet_obj.cell(row = to_load, column = 6)
        loading_pho = sheet_obj.cell(row = to_load, column = 7)
        loading_email = sheet_obj.cell(row = to_load, column = 8)
        loading_today = sheet_obj.cell(row = to_load, column = 9)

        #assign a variable the value of said cell
        id = loading_id.value
        dl = loading_dl.value
        fn = loading_fn.value
        ln = loading_ln.value
        dob = loading_dob.value
        ssn = loading_ssn.value
        pho = loading_pho.value
        email = loading_email.value
        today = loading_today.value

        idname = 'ID'#-------------just to make the ID variable readable
        idname = idname + str(id)#-just to make the ID variable readable

        locals()[idname] = [id,fn,ln,dob,ssn,pho,email,today]# convert determine idname value into 
#                                                              the actual variable and add a list 
#                                                              of the info as the value
        
        
        data.append([id,dl,fn,ln,dob,ssn,pho,email,today])#    Append IDNAME list into Data MAster list
        
        df = pd.DataFrame([data[x]], columns=('ID','DL','First Name','Last Name','DOB','SSN','Phone','Gmail','SIGN DATE'))
# my attempt to make the PANDA dataframe with the DATA list
# but when in the reality it just overwrite the previous Student info for obvius reasons
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using `pd.read_excel`?

```
import pandas as pd
path = "database.xlsx" #location
df = pd.read_excel(path)
```

Comment: That works if you have only one sheet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063458/reading-an-excel-file-in-python-using-pandas

Comment: this other one works if you have multiples sheets