# Dataframe does not get populated with the fields in the values area

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, powerbi

I have recently started with Python in Power BI and I am a noob in it.

through power query, I have imported some columns from an Excel file into the power query and all of the fields are dates and put in the values area.

in the Python code, I tried to bring these fields into a DataFrame named required_data so I can draw my visual but I got the following error
what should I do to import all the fields of the *mydata* on the right into the *required_data* DataFrame so the rest of the code runs smoothly and I can publish my visual
[image]

Comment: Please read the documentation for [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), [Reading an Excel file in python using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17063458/7758804)

Comment: In the documentation, everything is entered as literal. I need to use what I imported with the power query. There is no use in writing the name of columns as keys and typing that many dates as literals one by one as values

Comment: Your dataframe creation code makes no reference to the object created by **I have imported some columns from an Excel file into the power query and all of the fields are dates and put in the values area.**

Comment: sorry, I did not understand your point. would you please provide at least one line of code so I can see what you mean? I can not reference the mydata at all

Answer (score 0):

The data frame has already been created for you and you can reference it using the variable `dataset`, eg

```
# The following code to create a dataframe and remove duplicated rows is always executed and acts as a preamble for your script: 

# dataset = pandas.DataFrame(day, sex, smoker, time)
# dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates()

# Paste or type your script code here:

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.swarmplot(x="day",y="tip percent",data = dataset)

plt.show()
```

Comment: In another part of the code I tried to assign the dataset DataFrame to another variable but I could not do it. like df=dataset

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: I don't think it is assigned because the following lines throw an error

plt.xlim(dataset['Time Scale'].iloc[1]-tdelta,
         dataset['Time Scale'].iloc[-1]+tdelta)
plt.ylim(dataset['Time Scale'].iloc[1]-tdelta,
         dataset['Time Scale'].iloc[-1]+tdelta)

Comment: Simplify your code and post any error as part of your question.